# Limpar Panel a partir de um UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde vários UserControls serão mostrados em um Panel a partir do código abaixo:

```
UserControl1 u1 = new UserControl1();
            panel1.Controls.Add(u1);
```

E removo eles a partir deste código:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Porém, não estou conseguindo inserir este comando a partir de um  botão dentro do UserControl. Só consigo a partir do form onde está o Panel

Comment: Tens de colocar um pouco mais de código. Mas para ficares com a ideia, tens de tornar o objecto panel1 como public, e passá-lo para o constructor do UserControl para conseguires aceder a ele noutros objectos (neste caso, dentro do userControl). Ou então deixar esse panel1 como static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que pegar o evento do `Button` que está dentro do userControl.

no código do userControl, insira uma propriedade que retorne o Button como público. Assim:

```
public Button BotaoLimpar {get{ return buttonLimpar;}}
```

Agora quando criar o userControl, atribua o evento a ele, assim:

```
 private void AddUserControl()
 {
     UserControl1 u1 = new UserControl1();
     u1.BotaoLimpar.Click += buttonLimpar_Click;
     panel1.Controls.Add(u1);
 }

 private void buttonLimpar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     panel1.Controls.Clear();
 }
```

ou, você pode criar um evento dentro do seu userControl para disparar, quando o botão for clicado. É um pouco mais complicado, porém acho mais correto. Se preferir, faço o código dessa outra forma também.